# Conditional DisableProgramGroupPage in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to create a single installer for both normal and portable installs. For the portable install I am disabling all icons and uninstaller creation.

The only problem I am stuck at is how to disable program group page when running the portable install. Am I misunderstanding something here?

```
[Setup]
;This works as expected
Uninstallable=not IsPortable()
;This does NOT work, can't compile (DisableProgramGroupPage=yes alone compiles fine)
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes IsPortable()
```

Compilation fails with error

> Value of [Setup] section directive ... is invalid.

This is the `IsPortable()` function:

```pascal
function IsPortable(): Boolean;
begin
  if(StandardRadioButton.Checked = True) then
  Result := False
  else
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: The important note is in the `Uninstallable` directive reference by the *Valid values* title; it says *yes or no,* ***or a boolean expression***. That's what `DisableProgramGroupPage` does no have, so you cannot use your function there. Also note, that not all directives allow conditional evaluation at runtime and this might be one of them (have no time to check right now). If that is so, you can still skip the page in the `ShouldSkipPage` event handler as a workaround.

Comment: I see, I'll use ShouldSkipPage then. Where can I get IDs of built in pages?

Comment: These are documented in the bottom of the [`Event Functions`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Elaborating on @TLama's comment)*

The [`DisableProgramGroupPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_disableprogramgrouppage) does not support "boolean expression":

> **[Setup]: DisableProgramGroupPage**
>   Valid values: `auto`, `yes`, or `no`

Contrary to [`Uninstallable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable):

> **[Setup]: Uninstallable**
>   Valid values: `yes` or `no`, *or a boolean expression*

---

You can use [`ShouldSkipPage` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) instead:

```pascal
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if PageID = wpSelectProgramGroup then
  begin
    Result := IsPortable;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Good answer, works perfectly. You answered just as I wrote the exact same piece of code :)